# Hudson and CCRC integration

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, clearcase-remote-client

I am trying to configure the Clearcase Remote client with Hudson build.
I downloaded clearcase.hpi file.

There are 2 options Base Clearcase and UCM clearcase, i don't know which to use (not well know about CC).
So started with BaseClearcase.
given all inputs as asked in Hudson clear case input form.

Issue is throwing a exception

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cleartool"

Hudson is asking cleartool executable file, what it is? is it different from Clearcase Remote client install ? where to configure it hudson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected: cleartool is from a full ClearCase installation, which you don't have.

CCRC is a lightweight ClearCase installation, a client talking to a CCRC server through web request only.

You can try and use **[`rcleartool`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728)**, but I don't know if this will be compatible with the Hudson ClearCase plugin: if that plugin tries to create a snapshot or dynamic view, it won't work, since CCRC uses only [web views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm) (like snapshot view, but with slightly different parameters at the creation).

Support for CCRC is still pending ([JENKINS-5192](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5192)).